# What is the 'better' approach to configuring a tkinter widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've worked with tkinter a bit of a time now.
There are two ways for configuration or at at least I just know two:

1:  `frame.config(bg='#123456')`

2:  `frame["bg"] = '#123456'`

I use the latter more often. Only if there are more things to be done at the same time, the second seems useful for me.
Recently I was wondering if one of them is 'better' like faster or has any other advantage.

I don't think it's a crucially important Question but maybe someone knows it.

Comment: I don't think that there is any advantage to one way or the other.  I tend to use the first because it requires fewer code changes if I need to configure more attributes in the future.  I don't think that I even knew that second way would work.

Comment: You should be careful with a question like this, because it isn't particularly objective and will be very opinion based.  If you ask about something more objective, it is a better question.  For example, I suspect that the second way actually calls into the first way behind the scenes.  Asking if they are equivalent in that regard would be more objective.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind in the future

Comment: Indeed, under the hood, `frame['bg'] = foo` calls `frame.__setitem__('bg', foo)` 
and the [`__setitem__` method calls `configure`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1485).

Comment: If you have only one parameter to configure, they're basically equivalent.  If you need to set more than one parameter, `.config()` can set any number of them in a single statement, indexing requires a separate statement for each parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Studying the tkinter code base, we find the following:

```
class Frame(Widget):
    # Other code here

class Widget(BaseWidget, Pack, Place, Grid):
    pass

class BaseWidget(Misc):
    # other code here

class Misc:
    # various code
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.configure({key: value})
```

Therefore, the two methods are actually equivalent.  The line

```
frame['bg'] = '#123456'
```

is interpreted as `frame.__setitem__('bg','#123456')`, which after passing through the inheritance chain finds itself on the internal class `Misc` which simply passes it to the configure method.  As far as your question about efficiency is concerned, the first method is probably slightly faster because it doesn't need to be interpreted as much, but the speed difference is too little to be overly concerned with.

Comment: and keep in mind that the `.config()` method can change several parameters at once unlike the 2nd method. This would be a good reason to say the first method is a bit better as it takes less lines of code to achieve the same results over the second method.

Comment: That is a good point.  Yes, the config method is certainly preferable if setting multiple parameters.  As I said in my comment above, using it, even with one parameter, sets you up to easily add more parameters in the future.  However, the point here is that they are actually the same when you trace the execution, so it comes down a matter of style.